# Detect number of lines required by piece of text

Tags: actionscript-3

This one is for all the TextField wizards out there. I have a text field that displays 2 paragraphs of texts. The first one I want to be truncated to show only 3 lines of text maximum. The 2nd paragraph is to be appended to that text.

Is there a way I can show only the first 3 lines of the first paragraph? Think of it like an abstract for an article for the first paragraph.

I tried doing it with String.subStr(0, guestimate of 3 lines of chars) but it's pretty inconsistent in that some strings will take up 4 lines of the textfield.

I thought about doing 2 separate textfields but in the case of the first paragraph having only 1 line worth of chars, there will be gap of 2 lines worth of chars between the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [TextField#getLineOffset()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineOffset%28%29). It will return the character index of the first character on the specified line - you can use substr or substring to truncate the text accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
textField = new TextField();
textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
textField.width = _boundaryWidth;
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;
textField.multiline = true;
textField.wordWrap = true;
textField.text = _text;
textField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
while( textField.numLines > 3 )
{
    var txt:String = textField.getLineText(textField.numLines - 1 );
    textField.replaceText(textField.text.length - txt.length,textField.text.length, "");
    var numLines:int = textField.numLines;
}
```

This piece of code should do what you are looking for.

All that you need to do is check for the number of lines the text is covering. Set the width initially because that helps the textfield decide how many lines it needs to spread out into. I have not created a function which encompasses all this. But I guess that should be pretty simple to do since the whole function body is here.

Comment: Simple and good code, even if the var 'numLines' isn't useful.